# How to uniquely identify DOM elements while using little size for the identifier

Tags: javascript, html, dom, uniqueidentifier

I am working on a project where two browsers should synchronize their DOM elements. Whenever a DOM element changes on one browser only the changes and the position of the changed element get sent to the other browser by a websocket.

In order for this to work I need a way to give the changed element a uniquely identifier that uses a little amount of size while the other browser should be able to locate the position of the changed element.

What would be a good approach for this?

Comment: That's literally what the HTML [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) is for. It uniquely identifies a single element node in a DOM tree, obviating the need for things like CSS selectors or the older concept of an xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate *one-way* DOM-1 to DOM-2 you can use, in DOM-1, a `document` *MutationObserver*, which will notify you about:

- attributes changes per each node
- nodes that have been removed
- nodes that have been added
- nodes that have been moved, by combining the sequence of the previous notifications

If both DOM-1 and DOM-2 are identical since the beginning, an easy way to to uniquely map a node in DOM-1, and address it in DOM-2, is the following one:

```
const {indexOf} = [];
const nodePath = node => {
  const path = [];
  let parentElement;
  // crawl up to the document.documentElement
  while (parentElement = node.parentElement) {
    path.push(indexOf.call(parentElement.childNodes, node));
    node = parentElement;
  }
  return path;
};

const findNode = path => path.reduceRight(
  // crawl down from the document.documentElement
  (parentElement, i) => parentElement.childNodes[i],
  document.documentElement
);
```

In DOM-1 you would `const path = nodePath(anyNode)` and you'd find it in DOM-2 via `findNode(path)`.

**However**, the thing the mutation observer *won't* tell you, whenever its records populates `removedNodes` list, is where these nodes have been removed from.

To circumvent this limitation you need to store, in DOM-1, and likely through a *WeakMap*, all nodes that are appended in the document, so that you can always propagate the change to DOM-2.

```
// the most top script on the page (at least in DOM-1)
const paths = new WeakMap;
new MutationObserver(records => {
  for (const record of records) {
    for (const node of record.addedNodes)
      paths.set(node, nodePath(node));
  }
}).observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Now, whenever the **other** generic *MutationObserver*, in charge of notify, via Web sockets or anything else, DOM-2 for changes, you need to signal the operation type, which can be `attribute`, `inserted`, or `removed`, and for the `removed` case, you can send right away the path to crawl, in this case `paths.get(node)`.

I hope these details are useful, as what you are trying to do is complex, but not impossible, and I won't write the whole software for you, as that's not what this site is about

**P.S.** to have literally *all* nodes paths, you might also want to recursively set these paths in `record.addedNodes`, so that per each added node, you need to crawl all its `childNodes` and do so until all `childNodes` are mapped. This won't be fast, but it'll give you the ability to notify every single generic node on the page.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. A very detailed answer from which I learned a lot. 